# Numerical values for chance words.

Tags: probability, regular-language

We use *probabilistic words* such as "likely", "unlikely" and so in normal conversation. I would like for these rather vague notions to be given some mathematical precision.  As a way of doing that I've arbitrarily assigned values to them as follows (let P = probability)

1. Certain: P = 100%
2. Highly likely: 100% > P $\geq$ 75%
3. Likely: 75% > P > 50%
4. 50-50: P = 50% (may be)
5. Unlikely: 50% > P > 25%
6. Highly unlikely: 25% $\geq$ P > 0%
7. Impossible: P = 0%

Are these acceptable values or not? Why?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: This is a question of language more than a question of mathematics.  Colloquially, yes the general ranges you used are probably how most people interpret the phrases (*with specific breakpoints from one category to the next being more fluid than that*) but it should be emphasized that in casual conversation the things being discussed are things for which we explicitly do *not* have precise values assignable for them.

Comment: It may be worth also emphasizing that in colloquial use, "impossible" might yet be used to describe something which is merely *improbable* but still possible.  Similarly for certain.  Also of interest would be phrases like "almost impossible" or "almost certainly" which, although fluid in casual conversation like the rest, does have a specific meaning in more rigorous mathematical contexts.  See [almost surely on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely).

Comment: Danke JMoravitz, will need to look into that concept. As you so rightly pointed out, there's a *fluidity* in language that partly explains the existence of what I've referred to as *chance words*. Yet, *mathematical words* to be grasped *nonmathematically*, that's curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct interpretation of a phrase like "highly likely" depends heavily on the context of the statement. You won't be able to make a simple translation table like this that gives accurate results across all or even most statements.

I'll add one comment: People usually [overstate their confidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overconfidence_effect) about pretty much everything, and especially when dealing with highish probabilities. If someone says a result is 90% or 95% or 99% certain then the true probability is often much lower. So even when people literally make a precise numerical claim about probability, I still wouldn't recommend trusting it!

Comment: Gracias. The puzzle for me is how do people make sense of probability claims like "Him coming to the party? **Unlikely**!" *without* numbers? These words I mentioned in the question/OP were in use much, much before mathematicians studied & subsequently quantified the notion of *chance*.

Comment: People who hate math can still hear statements like that and then usually avoid being too surprised by whether "he" shows up at the party. You don't need numbers to build a loose mental model of how confident you should feel about something given that person X said it's probably true. Which may be totally different from the correct confidence level if person Y made the same claim, because maybe Y is usually very conservative about their claims or whatever.

Comment: I do get what you're saying. Still, one has to *grasp* the meaning of "likely" in a statement like "it's *likely* to rain", oui? If I were to ask "how good was the *skrd*?" you wouldn't be able to comprehend the question since "skrd" is (hopefully) a word you don't know.